# Pointers disappear after calling sub-routine of child class

Tags: c++

I am trying to do One class with some features that will be em common with other (Inheritance). This is my principal class:

```
class SREngineJulius_father {
        protected:
            bool g2pInit;
            Recog *recog;
            Jconf *jconf;
        public:
            bool InitG2P(std::string dic, std::string model, int pos_process_flag=-1);
            bool Init_AM(std::string configStr);
    };
```

The two function `InitG2P` and `Init_AM`, will make updates in `recog` and `jconf`. This updates is something that all child objects of the child class must have.

```
class SREngineJulius: public SREngineJulius_father
    {
        DFA_INFO *dfaInfo;
        WORD_INFO *wordInfo;
        WORD_INFO *wordInfo_init;

        Output lastResult;
        TListString lastCmdList;
        bool startNotifyCallbackLoop;
        bool terminate;
        bool pause;


        DFA_INFO* copy_dfa_info(DFA_INFO* dfa);
        DFA_INFO* create_commands_dfa_info();
        static void status_recready(Recog *recog, void *dummy);
        static void status_recstart(Recog *recog, void *dummy);
        static void output_result(Recog *recog, void *dummy);
        static void put_hypo_phoneme(WORD_ID *seq, int n, WORD_INFO *winfo);

        std::string ReplaceSpace(std::string &str);
        std::string RestoreSpace(std::string &str);

    public:
        bool InitG2P(std::string dic, std::string model, int pos_process_flag=-1);
        char* NotifyCallbackLoop(char *ficheiro_wav);//AXY5
        int SREngineJulius::Audio_Buffering(char* buffer_audio, int sizefile, int end_flag_, int flag_alocation);//AXY5
        void Callbacks();

    public:

        ~SREngineJulius();
        bool InitSREngine(std::string recoConfig);

        bool DynamicAddCommands(TListString &cmdlist, int startRecog = -1);
        bool DynamicAddCommands(std::string cmdlist, std::string sep=" ",  int startRecog = -1);
        void Release();

    };
```

So the problem is, when I call a routine of the child class, `recog` and `jconf` are deleted.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Right now it's almost impossible to even guess anything.

Comment: `InitG2P` is not declared as virtual in the base class, though redefined in the child class. Is that on purpose, or (most likely) forgotten?

Comment: What you have shown and explained does not provide any sort of guarantee that the methods cannot mess up with recog and jconf. It is really necessary to debug the code to see where the harm occurs.

Comment: I will dig in the code, and find a minimal example. And then I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

You should make functions in your class that edify the two variables. Try inserting those into a anonymous struct. That way they're easily accessible.

Remember:
. =reference
-> =pointer

Lastly, you are changing recog in a couple of those function declarations.
Try to make sure that the functions are friendly in the functions you make. If they are not, you won' be able to use them.

P.s. children of child classes, these need accessor functions. They have to change the pointers through upward inheritance. So you would want to have the child class of the grandparent have a class that changes it's pointers. You would do that by having a function which accesses the child, in the grandchild. That way you're receding back into the function. That's how it's related.

Comment: What does 'edify the two variables' mean?

Comment: To edify, is to change the representation of. Here, I was imllying the value.